# Move divs up from bottom in wrapper with css

Tags: html, css

I have a specific problem which I'm stuck at.

I have a square, in which there is a picture and text.
What i need to do is, when the box is hovered, the text, which is hidden, should appear from bottom and push the image up (overflow:hidden on the wrapper will cut it off).
The text is arbitrary length, and the action should be css-only (no javascript)

The html is:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="image"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" /></div>
    <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,</div>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
.wrapper {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.content {
    height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.wrapper:hover .content {
     height:auto;   
}
```

(this is just a sample)

Here is a jsFiddle of it: 
http://jsfiddle.net/a136ddj8/2/

(if you do not see anything on hover, remove the overflow:hidden from the wrapper class)

Any ideas on how to achieve this? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this case you can use an extra-wrapper:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="image"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" /></div>
      <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then with CSS you can position that extra container absolute to acomplish the push effect...Also you can't animate `height` to auto instead use a fixed value on `max-height`.

```
.content {
    max-height:0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.wrapper:hover .content {
     max-height:500px;   
}
```

**<kbd>Check the Snippet Below</kbd>**

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrap {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.image img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.content {
  max-height: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper:hover .content {
  max-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
    </div>
    <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Play with position properties.

Here is the demo

```css
.wrapper {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.content {
   
    overflow:hidden;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    position:relative;
    padding:20px;
    top:0
}

.wrapper:hover .content {
     height:auto; 
    top:-200px;
    
    
}
.image img{ position:relative;transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease; top:0;}
.wrapper:hover img { top:-200px;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="image"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" /></div>
    <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,</div>
</div>
```

Positioning with css will make the animation. Here is the demo.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you could make this a little more semantic by using a figure and figure caption. But then, you're limited by a couple of things. If you want to do this without javascript, you'll be limited to a fixed-height on the container. Here's a snippet:

```css
.slide-up-caption { /* main figure element, requires fixed height */
   height: 200px;
   width: 200px;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
   border: 1px solid black;
}


.slide-up-caption img { display: block } /* clears spacing issues */

.slide-up-caption-inner { /* wrapper around img and caption that sticks to bottom */
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.slide-up-caption figcaption {
    height: 0;
    padding: 0 .5em; /* no padding on top & bottom to make it hidden completely */
    background: black;  
    color: white;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s; /* transition just for fun */
    -moz-transition: all .25s;
    transition: all .25s;
}

.slide-up-caption:hover figcaption {
  height: auto; /* only think you really need here */
  padding: .5em; /* add padding for style */
  -webkit-transition: all .25s; /* transition for fun */
  -moz-transition: all .25s;
  transition: all .25s;
 }
```

```html
<figure class="slide-up-caption">
  <div class="slide-up-caption-inner">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="placeholder img">
    <figcaption>This is demo content.</figcaption>
  </div>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should lead you the right way. Obviously, you'll want to play with the styling. The main thing is using positioning, not height.

http://jsfiddle.net/wilchow/a136ddj8/5/

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
.content {
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 210px;
    margin:0;
    padding: 5px;
}
.wrapper:hover .content {
    height:auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I just noticed you wanted to push the image up. @Danko has it correct.